# How to sample `n=1000` vector from Multivariate Normal distribution?

Tags: python

I want to sample the number of `m=10` of size `n=1000` vectors (1000 dimension) from Multivariate Normal distribution with mean vector `(0,0,..,0)` and covariance matrix identity `I_n` and then divided by its l_2 norm.
[image]

---

Based on the answer, I try the following code:

```
import random
m = 2
n = 5
random.seed(1000001)
x = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(m), np.eye(m), size=n)
print(x)
```

```
[[ 0.93503543 -0.00605634]
 [-0.42033252  0.08350352]
 [ 0.58507136 -0.07849799]
 [ 0.79762498  0.26868063]
 [ 1.31544479  0.79820179]]
```

Normalized

```
# Calculate the norms on axis zero
axis_0_norms = np.linalg.norm(x,axis = 0)
#print(f"Norms on axis 0 = {axis_0_norms}\n")

# Normalise the arrays
normalized_x = x/axis_0_norms
print("Normalized data:\n", normalized_x)
```

```
Normalized data:
 [[ 0.48221541 -0.00712517]
 [-0.21677341  0.09824033]
 [ 0.30173234 -0.09235142]
 [ 0.41135025  0.31609774]
 [ 0.6783997   0.93906949]]
```

But `0.48221541**2+(-0.00712517)**2` is not 1.

Comment: Where in your code are the numbers m=10 and n=1000 supposed to appear? Why does the number 500 appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.zeros()`, and `np.eye()`, and `size`, to provide the parameters for the [multivariate_normal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html) function in order to create the array. Then **normalize** the data using the `l2 norm` parameter of the [normalize](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) function from sklearn. We can then validate this l2 normalization by checking the **sum of the squared values in each row** of the data.

So firstly, let us create the array:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

# Set the seed for reproducibility
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

# Create the array
m = 10
n = 1000
X = rng.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(m), np.eye(m), size=n)

# Display the data within a dataframe
df_X = pd.DataFrame(X)
print("Original X:\n", df_X.head(5))
```

**OUTPUT:** 
Showing the **first 5/1000 rows** of the Original array (X)

```
Original X:
```

[image: Original X]

---

Now let us **normalize the array** using the `preprocessing.normalize()` function from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html).

```py
# Normalize X using l2 norms
X_normalized = preprocessing.normalize(X, norm='l2')

# Display the normalized array within a dataframe
df_norm = pd.DataFrame(X_normalized)
print("X_normalized:\n", df_norm.head(5))
```

**OUTPUT:** 
Showing the first 5/1000 rows of the normalized array.

```
X_normalized:
```

[image: X_normalized]

---

And finally, we can now check the validity of this normalized array by checking that the
**sum of the squared values** in each **row** is equal to `1`.

```py
# Confirm l2 normalization by checking the sum of the squared values in each row. 
# Should equal 1 in each row
X_normalized_squared = X_normalized ** 2
X_sum_squared = np.sum(X_normalized_squared, axis=1)

# Display the sum of the squared values for each row within a dataframe
df_sum = pd.DataFrame(X_sum_squared, columns=["Sum"])
print("X_sum_squared:\n", df_sum.head(5))
```

**OUTPUT:** 
Showing the first 5/1000 rows.
Sum of the squared values for each row.

```
X_sum_squared:
```

[image: X_sum_squared]

Comment: Yes! Thanks! We will have `m=10` vectors. So how can we normalized them?

Comment: Another way to normalize the array is through scikit-learn's `normalize` function: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html

Comment: Thanks! How do you use `from numpy.linalg import norm` to normlize the vector? I know how to normalize one vector but these are `m=10` vectors.

Comment: Did use the L_2 norm but not L_1?

Comment: You may or may not need to specify the ord value as per https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html

Comment: Do you mean `x = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(n), np.eye(n), size=n)`? We got 10 vectors of 1000 dimensions, so they are in an array, how do I extract one of them? I tried `normalized_x[1]`, but how can there be `normalized_x[11]` too?

Comment: Sorry, I tried your code in a simple case. But it seems does not work? Maybe I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I think I may have been getting my L_1 and L_2's mixed up. Let me review and update with explanations.

Comment: Ok - have updated my answer - hopefully this makes more sense.